# How to adjust mat-header-cell width in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can we customize or change the mat-header-cell in angular? I wanted to change the width but it is not taking any effect. Thank you,.

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear="true">Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is preventing you from applying a style or a class to the cell ?

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
       <mat-header-cell style="width: 400px" *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disableClear="true">Name</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4r2gb8-x3mbq2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: check the blitz, it does work (you can like set `min-width:1000px` and you will see how big the table become. If it doesn't work in your case, show a stackblitz with your code so we can help.